# How to change label

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<label ng-repeat="day in days">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="activityDays[$index]" /> {{day}}
    <br />
</label>
```

How can I change text of label when checked?

Comment: for using css it `label` should be the sibling of `input`

Comment: you can use something like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ykd8eo7o/) hiding and showing content when `:checked`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can loop through the `input`'s  parent's children, and change its `.data` if its `day`.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (this.parentNode.childNodes[i].data !== undefined) {
        if (this.parentNode.childNodes[i].data.trim() == 'day') {
          this.parentNode.childNodes[i].data = 'night'
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < this.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (this.parentNode.childNodes[i].data !== undefined) {
        if (this.parentNode.childNodes[i].data.trim() == 'night') {
          this.parentNode.childNodes[i].data = 'day'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<label ng-repeat="day in days">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="activityDays[$index]" />day
  <br />
</label>
```